# Assigning variables with values inside a loop - Express.js

Tags: reactjs, express, server

this may seem ridiculous, but i cannot use arrays here.

```
let var1 = null;
let var2 = null;
let var3 = null;
let var4 = null;
```

I want to assign some value into these variables by using a loop using express.js

```
for(let i=0; i<3; i++)
{
 var`${[i]}` = 'Some Value';
}
```

This did work for react, but its not working for server side. express.js

Comment: Do you have the option of putting them in an object? Then you could do `obj['var' + i] = 'Some Value';`

Comment: i cant actually, these data was sent as a FormData variable which had many data appended to it. Tried to append arrays there, but couldnt. so only way was naming variables dynamically and sending them to server.  But im not able to access them here like i did from front end

Comment: I see. If you get a request with data created with `FormData`, can you not do `request.body['var' + i]`? Sorry, I might be misunderstanding you.

Comment: Hey ! thanks !  It did work !

Comment: i was trying 

req.body.`file${[ i ]}`  and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this may seem ridiculous

The ridiculous situation seems to require yet another ridiculous solution of having to utilize a `global` object.

```js
PS C:\misc\sources> node                            
> [1,2,3,4].forEach(id => global['var' + id] = null)
undefined                                           
> var1                                              
null                                                
> var2                                              
null                                                
> var3                                              
null                                                
> var4                                              
null                                                
> var5                                              
ReferenceError: var5 is not defined
```

On client-side, you can utilize `window` instead.

```js
[1,2,3,4].forEach(id => window['var' + id] = null)
console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
console.log(var3);
console.log(var4);
console.log(var5);
```

Answer (score 0):

> > you could try this

```
let obj = {
    var1: null,
    var2: null,
    var3: null,
   }

Object.keys(obj).forEach((item) => {
  item = "SOme value"
})
```